# sort vector in increasing order of frequency of elements using stl

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I am trying to sort a vector of integers in order of increasing frequency. I have declared a global map which stores counts of the integers and have used it in custom comparator, however I am getting wrong answer. While checking online([here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-array-elements-frequency-set-3-using-stl/)) I have found implementations using pairs that seem to work fine. What am I doing wrong ?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
unordered_map<int,int> m;

bool cm(int a,int b){
   if(m[a]<m[b])
       return true;
   return false;
}
int main(){
       int n;
       cin>>n;
       vector<int> v(n);
       
       for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
           cin>>v[i];
           m[v[i]]++;
       }

       sort(v.begin(),v.end(),cm);
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn’t compile.  Please put together a [mcve].

Comment: For the sample input I provided, this code worked for me. What testcase has failed?

Comment: Please post your result as well, your provided testcase works fine for me.

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/BkrS_v9fw Worked for that testcase as well. It is possible, that there may be a case on how to handle when the frequencies of two numbers match?

Comment: 8
2 4 1 5 3 5 1 3
For this testcase I get the following output :
2 4 1 5 3 5 1 3

Answer (score 3):

Your ordering says that all numbers that occur with the same frequency are equivalent.

For example, in

```
8 2 4 1 5 3 5 1 3
```

8, 2, and 4 occur once, and 1, 3, and 5 occur twice, so you have two groups of equivalent values. You define no ordering within these groups.
So it's not that much of a surprise that the output

```
8 2 4 1 5 3 5 1 3
```

has the elements that occur once first, and then the elements that occur twice, with no particular order withing each "section".

You need an ordering that also takes the values into acount.
Something like this:

```
bool cm(int a,int b){
    return m[a] < m[b] || (m[a] == m[b] && a < b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I was missing.Clears everything

Comment: @StPiere No, it won't. What makes you think that?

Comment: ah, overseen you are using global map in comparator.sorry.